# How to get out of airplane mode

Tags: airplane-mode

Ubuntu 20.04 recently went into airplane mode, how to get out? I tried to use the rfkill command and it did not work and the iwconfig

Comment: See Settings/Wifi: there should be a switch at the top. Doesn't that work?

Comment: it will default to airplane if you disable wifi in bios or on your keyboard if any of those are possible. Those are hardware locks.. so you need to unlock it from  there too.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities:

- Software Lock: This occurs when disable WiFi in Settings. Simply Re-enable WiFi in Settings.
- Hardware Lock: This occurs when you press the Keyboard key (there is one on most laptops -- look or it!), or in some BIOS setting. Ubuntu cannot unlock hardware locks - you must find that Keyboard key or BIOS setting again.

See the output of `rfkill` to determine if yours is a Software or Hardware lock. Here's an example of rfkill output after I toggle my laptop keyboard's airplane-mode key:

```
    $ rfkill
    ID TYPE DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
     0 wlan phy0   unblocked   blocked
```

And after I toggle it again:

```
    $ rfkill
    ID TYPE DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
     0 wlan phy0   unblocked unblocked
```